# how to convert a normal list to 2d list + changing the values to integers

Tags: python, list

I want to convert a normal list to 2d list and want to change the numbers to integers instead of str
I have somthing like this

```
my_list = ['00000000', '00000000', '00111000', '00101000', '00101000', '00000000', '00000000', '00000000']
```

I want somthing like this using for loop:

```
my_list = [[00000000], [00000000], [00111000], [00101000], [00101000], [00000000], [00000000], [00000000]]
```

Comment: Try to break down the problem. If you only had one element to deal with, how would you transform it? i.e. `'00111000'` to `[00111000]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a list comprehension here:

```py
my_list = ['00000000', '00000000', '00111000', '00101000', '00101000', '00000000', '00000000', '00000000']
output = [[int(x)] for x in my_list]
print(output)  # [[0], [0], [111000], [101000], [101000], [0], [0], [0]]
```

Note that there is no Python integer literal `00000000`, which is really the same as `0`.  If you need the leading zeroes, then you should leave your data as strings.

**Edit:**

To get a 2D list of single numbers from each string, use:

```py
my_list = ['00000000', '00000000', '00111000', '00101000', '00101000', '00000000', '00000000', '00000000']
output = [[int(x) for x in list(y)] for y in my_list]
print(output)
# [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], ...
```

Comment: What if I want to separate each number by a comma?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but if you want a 1D list of integers, then use: `[int(x) for x in my_list]`

Comment: I meant for example: [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0etc..  ] to keep the zeros